# how to add jquery datetime picker with laravel project?

Tags: jquery, laravel

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text">
    </input>
    <span class="add-on">
              <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-
              calendar">
              </i>
              </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my blade view.But onclicking the inputfiled it displays nothing.Even the icons were not displayed.

Comment: set  datetimepicker1 id to input text and try like this $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR'
  });

Comment: and also add js datepicker library

Comment: will u please specify the library of it

Comment: also it throws error messages like  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: you can use any js library for it. like https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Because of you are not add datetimepicker library so through error

Comment: It also throws error messages like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

As the documetation of the jquery datetime picker mention over here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

You need to add the jquery-ui.js along with the jquery-ui.css. So your correct working code would be like this as showing in this fiddle

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="well">
  <div  class="input-append date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  type="text" />
    <span class="add-on">
              <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-
              calendar">
              </i>
              </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working.But I need it with timepicker also.Also I can only able to view the calender from your snippet and can't able to select the dates

Comment: ie., onclicking with the input field it should show up the calender and time with seconds

Comment: For that I think you must use datetime js

Comment: will you please specify how to include it

Comment: You can refer this link here on https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and there are plenty others which provide the same funtionality

Comment: Can you share the error you faced as it is quite simple to implement that

Comment: I am not getting error messages while running it.But it not even shows up the calendar and timings

Comment: Can you create separate question with that code which you have used it.